# size of template parameter pack pointer

Tags: c++, c++17

Im a little stuck.

How would i go about getting the size of the struct inside the parameter pack loop

if i pass just the struct i get the correct size, but if i pass it by a pointer or a ref the size is always 8

```
struct foo_s {
    int i1;
    int i2;
    int i3;
};

template<typename ...Args>
void Call(Args&& ...args)
{
    std::size_t index = 0;
    auto process = [&] <typename Arg> (Arg && arg, std::size_t index) {
        std::size_t size = sizeof(Arg); // always 8
    };
    (process(std::forward<Args>(args), index++), ...);
}


int main() {

    foo_s foo = { 1, 2, 3 };
    foo_s* pFoo = &foo;

    Call(pFoo);
}
```

Comment: That's correct though. If you want it to strip pointers, use `std::remove_pointer_t<T>`, but be prepared for surprises. However, a reference should always have the size of its target. It doesn't exist notionally. The implementation-defined size is only available if you put it in a struct and take the size of that.

Comment: @dfri and remove_pointer of course cause that's what op is after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can remove the reference, then remove the pointer if it's a pointer type, and get the size of that:

```
std::size_t size = sizeof(std::remove_pointer_t<std::remove_reference_t<Arg>>);
```

If it's not a pointer type then `remove_pointer_t` will still give us `T` so there's no danger here.

This is of course deducing size by type, you could also do it by argument if you have it available, this lacks the flexibility of type `sizeof` though because it requires pointer-only types. It'd be done like :

```
std::size_t size = sizeof(*arg);
```

Comment: You can go ahead and add my solution if you want. I'll delete mine, no point in cross-referencing answers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`std::remove_cvref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cvref) to get the underlying type. If you care about pointer types too, add a layer of `std::remove_pointer`.

```
auto process = [&] <typename Arg> (Arg && arg, std::size_t index) {
    using UnderlyingType = typename std::remove_cvref<Arg>::type;         
    std::size_t size = sizeof(UnderlyingType); 
};
```

I firstly wrote that `std::decay` is also a possibility. While it behaves correctly for references, it does not have the resquested behaviours on arrays and pointer types.

Comment: As this question has been tagged as C++17, you may want to make use of the `_t` alias templates for traits (added as per C++14) instead of explicitly having to type out the verbose `typename ... ::type`.